# How can I change the screen position of krunner in KDE Plasma 5.x?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, kde-plasma-workspace

I have just updated to [Kubuntu 15.04](http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-15.04) and can't find out how to change the position of `krunner` (the little search window that appears when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) so that it appears in the center of the screen instead of at the top. Is this still possible? If yes, how can I change this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the feature that you're looking for was removed. There is a [submitted change](https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/118591/) that restores the FreeFloating feature, but I don't know if it is implemented anywhere.

Comment: It is possible editing its [configuration file](https://superuser.com/a/1486294/294180).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to use this workaround in kubuntu 16.04: I created a special Window Rule for the krunner window to enforce a certain screen position.

**Details:**
In the system settings application, goto Workspace, Window Management, Window Rules

- create a new Window rule:

  - Window class (application): choose "Exact Match" from the drop down list, enter: `krunner` into the field (or use the Detect Window Properties button)

[image]

- on the second tab Size & Position:

  - check the first box Position
  - choose "Apply Initially"
  - enter some numbers into the field: I entered `570,400` for about the middle of my screen (that may vary depending on the display)

[image]

- click OK

[image]

- click Apply

Anyway, this window is meant to be placed in the upper part of the screen - if set too close to the bottom, it will jump upward when the list of findings is long enough.

[image]

Comment: In order to make it work: Window class (application): choose "Exact Match" from the drop down list, enter: `krunner`. In the answer it says: "enter: `krunner krunner` into the field".   - Do you know a manual or something on the rest of possible settings (dimension e.g.)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6kugmvsI_Q

Answer (score 10):

This can be done on KDE Plasma 5, without special KWin (or any WM) rules.

**GUI method** (since [Plasma 5.20](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-desktop/-/blob/v5.20.0/kcms/runners/kcm.cpp#L80-87))

- Open System Settings and search Krunner
- Set the desired "*Position on screen*"

[image: KDE System Settings for Krunner]

**Text method** (since early [Plasma 5](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-workspace/-/blob/v5.0.0/krunner/view.cpp#L60))

Edit `~/.config/krunnerrc` and make sure that `FreeFloating` is set to `true`.

```
[General]
FreeFloating=true
```

Then restart KRunner.

```sh
krunner --replace & disown
```

---

As @cipricus mentions in the comments, it is also possible to set other properties, like the font size, e.g.:

```sh
[General]
font=Noto Sans,12,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
```

Every coma separated argument has a [different meaning](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#toString). The most relevant are the first and second ones, which is the Font family and the Point size.

Comment: Where are things like this documented?  I ran into this trying to accomplish same as OP, and would love to see what else can be modified using config file. I've found an old reference to a krunnerrc global with no defs though, and it's from kde4, and no equivalent seems to exist in my install of Plasma 5.

Comment: @sandroid I don't know about any documentations, but you can look directly at the source: https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-workspace/-/blob/6d0c45a6bc29ad2329156f3f97a27ef156cd3f9b/krunner/view.cpp#L160 and search for other `readEntry` occurrences :)

Comment: not in Plasma 18

Comment: @cipricus For the GUI method you need Plasma 5.20+ and for the Text method, it works on pretty much any Plasma 5 version.

Comment: Also, the size can be changed in the same file, thus increasing the size of the whole window: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/cpsz6h/how_to_make_fonts_in_krunner_bigger_how_to_make/ewrdgdy?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: Good idea, have added it with some details.

Comment: What about the application icons? They are small anyway, and look disproportionately so after increasing the size of the font..

Comment: Works on KUbuntu 20.04.